# How should I print a const char *a[] as a descending, numbered list?

Tags: arrays, printing

I'm taking an introductory C++ class, and for part of an assignment, we had to print out a list of eight instructions. We were told to do it like this:

```
using namespace std;

//omitted code

cout << "1. (first instruction)" << endl;
cout << "2. (second instruction)" << endl;
//[...]
cout << "8. (eighth instruction)" << endl;
```

But I'm sure there's better ways to do it. The way I understand it, if I declare something like

```
const char *instr[] = {
    "(first instruction)",
    "(second instruction)",
    //[...]
    "(eighth instruction)"
}
```

that will function like an array of strings. Also, the way I understand it, the asterisk creates a pointer that is somehow linked to each string in the array. If I want the output to look like

```
1. (first instruction)
2. (second instruction)

...

8. (eighth instruction)
```

how can I best go about printing the instructions as shown, while having them stored in some sort of variable, like a list or array?

In my mind, I would like to somehow loop through `instr[]` and perhaps use pointer arithmetic (admittedly, something I've only heard of, but never used) to append the numbers in front of the strings, but if there is a way to use `cout` and not loop anything, or a better way to declare the list of strings than as a `const char *`, or both, I'm all ears.

P.S. This is my first StackExchange question, so my apologies in advance if there is a similar question already posted that I couldn't find, if my writing is unclear, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to acheive your desired output is to use a **string array** and display array elements using **loop**. You may try the below code.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() 
{
  int count = 8; // number of elements you need in array
  string colour[count] = {"(first instruction)", "(second instruction)", "(third instruction)", "(fourth instruction)","(fifth instruction)","(sixth instruction)","(seventh instruction)","(eighth instruction)"}; 

  // for loop to print array elements
  for (int i = 0; i < count; i++){
    cout<<i+1<<". "<<colour[i]<<endl;        
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Hope this helps you.